# Open photos in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, photo

In my Flutter app I'm showing some images, currently when I click on them I can download them but I wanted to change that, so that when I click on the image it opens, does anyone know how I can do this?

An example would be gmail, where you receive the files and when you click on them they open and then you have the option to download

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Image Thumb Widget

```
ListTile(
  leading: Image.network(imageUrl),
  title: const Text('Image file'),
  subtitle: const Text('Tap for preview'),
  onTap: () => showPreview(imageUrl),
)
```

Image Preview Dialog

```
void showPreview(String url) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (c) => AlertDialog(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  const Expanded(child: Text('Image File')),
                  IconButton(
                      onPressed: () => download(url),
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.download))
                ],
              ),
              content: Image.network(url),
            ));
  }
```

Download Code

```
void download(String url) {
    http.get(Uri.parse(url)).then((value) {
      if (value.statusCode == 200) {
        Uint8List bytes = value.bodyBytes;
        print('Bytes :: ${bytes.length}');
      }
    });
  }
```

I used [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package for downloads

Answer (score 0):

For displaying an image from a known URL, you just need to use `Image.network()`

Here is a simple example:

```
 Image.network(
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501927023255-9063be98970c?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
            )
```